# How to Make Carousel View of Screens without Navigation in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I would like to implement a dynamic carousel view of screens (similar to [Swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper)). I was thinking of creating a `View` with conditional rendering that would display a screen by `selectedId` corresponding to each screen, but that would cause a re-render on every screen, unless I have a state for each one of them.

Is there any better solution to make a carousel view of screens without using navigation and keep the data on the screen saved?

Comment: I suppose one of the solutions would be making a ```FlatList``` with a conditionally rendered buttons at the bottom which would display continuation of the screen (with ```scrollEnabled={false}```, pagination and ```scrollToIndex``` method with correct ```ref```). I will post an answer if this method would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [react-native-progress-steps](https://github.com/colbymillerdev/react-native-progress-steps) for this solution. I have modified the config file a little and wrote a dummy data template for it.

Dummy data:

```
const reviewData = [
    {
        id: "1",
        serviceID: 0,
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        serviceID: 1,
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        serviceID: 2,
    },
];
```

render (disregard colors):

```
<View style={styles.container}>
            <ProgressSteps
                activeStepIconColor={defaultColors.white}
                completedProgressBarColor={settings.colors.primary}
                progressBarColor={defaultColors.light}
                activeStepIconBorderColor={settings.colors.primary}
                completedStepIconColor={settings.colors.primary}
                disabledStepIconColor={defaultColors.light}
                activeStepNumColor={defaultColors.dark}
                disabledStepNumColor={defaultColors.mediumLight}
            >
                {reviewData.map((item, index) => (
                    <ProgressStep
                        nextBtnStyle={styles.nextButtonStyle}
                        previousBtnStyle={
                            index === 0
                                ? styles.disabledButton
                                : styles.prevButtonStyle
                        }
                        nextBtnTextStyle={styles.nextButtonTextStyle}
                        previousBtnTextStyle={styles.prevButtonTextStyle}
                        previousBtnText={`Назад`}
                        nextBtnText={`Дальше`}
                        finishBtnText={`Завершить`}
                        previousBtnDisabled={index === 0 ? true : false}
                    >
                        <View style={{ alignItems: "left" }}>
                            <AppText>
                                {item.serviceID},{index}
                            </AppText>
                        </View>
                    </ProgressStep>
                ))}
            </ProgressSteps>
        </View>
```

I am satisfied with the solution, but if you have any other solutions, please let me know :)
[image]